# how to tell DDP to selectively observe change certain field,, instead all defined fields..?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ddp

we normally publish data as follow...

```
Meteor.publish('items', function(a) {
  return Items.find(a, {fields: {observeA:1, observeB:1, noobserveA:1, noobserveB:1}});
});
```

i have conditions as follow...

- `observeA` and `observeB` are reactive data,, so i need to observe them...
- `noobserveA` and `noobserveB` are static data,, so i don't need to observe them...

with above publication,, DDP still observe `noobserveA` and `noobserveB`..

how to tell DDP not to observe noobserveA and noobserveB..??

what i can think possible is to directly control published record... but i don't have even single idea how to make it work.. advanced publication feel too much for me for now...

```
Meteor.publish('items', function(a) {
  var self = this;
  var handle = Items.find(a || {}).observeChanges({
    changed: function(id, fields) {
      self.changed("itemdata", id, fields);
    }
  });
  self.ready();
  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

after this what should i do..?? i'm stuck with no idea what i'm doing right now... so if you know how to not to observer `noobserveA` and `noobserveB` either with advanced publication or other idea,, feel free to write answer... what i need is not to observe `noobserveA` and `noobserveB` field... that's it and that's all...

thank Youu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you store `noobserveA` and `noobserveB` into local collection?

After you store into local collection, you fetch `noobserveA` and `noobserveB` from local collection. Since local collection has no connection with server, then every update in server won't have any effect with `noobserveA` and `noobserveB`. Then, `noobserveA` and `noobserveB` would be static as you wish.

By this, you don't have to touch Advanced Publications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a straightforward way to do this, but this might work:

The idea is that we set up an observer on the "observe" fields.  Then, when a doc is added, we loop through the "noObserve" fields and get their value by doing a db lookup.  After that, we don't monitor the noObserve fields.

You may or may not need to do the same thing in the "changed" callback depending on your desired functionality.

```
Meteor.publish("myPub", function(docId) {

    let self = this;
    let observeFields = {observeA: 1, observeB: 1};
    let noObserveFields = ['noObserveA', 'noObserveB'];

    let cursor = myCollection.find(docId, {fields: observeFields});

    let handle = cursor.observeChanges({
        added: function(id, fields) {
            let doc = myCollection.findOne(id);
            noObserveFields.forEach(function(f) {
                fields[f] = doc[f];
            });
            self.added("my_collection", id, fields);    
        },
        changed: function(id, fields) {
            self.changed("my_collection", id, fields);
        },
        removed: function(id) {
            self.removed(id);
        }
    });

    self.ready();

    self.onStop(function() {
        handle.stop();
    });
});
```

Comment: hi @bluebird thank You for your answer... upvoted for your make sense idea... i'll take a look your code after i finish my exam.. thanks again...